# How to combine statebox and map/reduce in riak

Tags: erlang, mapreduce, riak

Is it possible to combine statebox and map/reduce in riak? Can not find any examples, and statebox riak api does not provide any kind of map/reduce functionality as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside mapreduce phases you could write any erlang code. So you could use statebox modules from there, but you will get some complexity with this:

1. you must have statebox modules on riak's path ([add_paths](http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/references/Configuration-Files/) option)
2. you will need feed right put and [get](https://github.com/mochi/statebox_riak/blob/master/src/statebox_riak.erl#L175) options to statebox
3. you will also need all statebox's deps on riak side (including riakc)